# How do I replace data toggle text with a glyphicon? (Using Rails and JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the acts_as_votable gem. Right now the like and dislike buttons are functioning correctly and the likes are saved to database. What I need is to replace the "Like" and "Dislike" text into Glyphicons. It does not work now because the **data: { toggle_text: 'Like'** portion only accepts a text value, and the JS is hooked up to data-toggle-text.

How should I approach this? Thanks for your help.

likes.js.coffee file

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.vote', (status,data,xhr)->
  # update counter
  $(".votes-count[data-id=#{data.id}]").text data.count

  # toggle links
  $("a.vote[data-id=#{data.id}]").each ->
    $a = $(this)
    href = $a.attr 'href'
    text = $a.text()
    $a.text($a.data('toggle-text')).attr 'href', $a.data('toggle-href')
    $a.data('toggle-text', text).data 'toggle-href', href
    return

  return
```

show.html.erb file

```
<% if current_user.liked? @review %>
<%= link_to "Dislike", dislike_review_path(@review), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Like', toggle_href: like_review_path(@review), id: @review.id } %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Like", like_review_path(@review), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Dislike', toggle_href: dislike_review_path(@review), id: @review.id } %>
<% end %>

<span class="votes-count" data-id="<%= @review.id %>">
<%= @review.get_likes.size %>
</span>
users like this
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do something like that

**likes.js.coffee**

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.vote', (status,data,xhr)->
  # update counter
  $(".votes-count[data-id=#{data.id}]").text data.count

  # toggle links
  $("a.vote[data-id=#{data.id}]").each ->
    $a = $(this)
    href = $a.attr 'href'
    text = $a.html()
    $a.html($a.data('toggle-text')).attr 'href', $a.data('toggle-href')
    $a.data('toggle-text', text).data 'toggle-href', href
    return

  return
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.liked? @review %>
  <%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>'.html_safe, dislike_review_path(@review), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty'></i>".html_safe, toggle_href: like_review_path(@review), id: @review.id } %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>'.html_safe, like_review_path(@review), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></i>".html_safe, toggle_href: dislike_review_path(@review), id: @review.id } %>
<% end %>

<span class="votes-count" data-id="<%= @review.id %>">
<%= @review.get_likes.size %>
</span>
users like this
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it doesn't seem to work and it shows <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i> in plain text rather than rendering it as a glyphicon.

Comment: @Joshua could you check an improved answer?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Cheers.